Flying burger spewing oil in the middle of the ocean
There is a film i saw a clip of as a kid that my family was watching together when i was six.
The scene shows a man (possibly standing on something) in the middle of an ocean or sea, and a hamburger with crazy eyes flys up to him and they have a dialogue about something. The conversation ends with the hamburger spewing a punch of black fluid on the man's face and flying off.
This was in the VHS era, so my older brother and i insisted on rewatching that scene over and over because it was funny.  Sadly this is all i remember about the film.  It almost looks like something out of a Terry Gilliam flick, but i don't think it is.
This was in '94 in the USA. Pretty sure it was a movie on vhs, and it was live action. Definitely wasn't *Batteries not Included. I recalled being bored with the scene before and after the dream-like burger scene, so i don't remember watching anything else.

When were you six?

And where were you six?

What VHS tape were you watching? Was it a movie or just recorded of the TV? If it was a movie trailer all we know right now is that it came out after Top Gun was released on VHS. If it was a commercial you randomly recorded, it might have been for an old Atari video game called "Fast Food".

Was this live action? or animated?

Good Burger has a flying burger dream sequence, but there's no ocean or oil spewing.

I don't think it was a burger but rather a cupcake. I believe you're after the 1994 comedy Cabin Boy which was co-produced by Tim Burton:

Nathaniel Mayweather (Chris Elliott) is a snobbish, self-centered, virginal man. He is invited by his father (portrayed by Elliott's real life father Bob Elliott (comedian)) to sail to Hawaii aboard the Queen Catherine. [...]
[After] floating [on a] raft for a week, Nathaniel has little to eat or drink, begins consuming salt water and suffers extreme sunburn after confusing cooking oil as lotion. He also realizes he might be going insane after sighting Kenny's ghost and seeing a floating cupcake that spits tobacco.

You can see the scene here, though without the original dialogue (the floating crazy-eyed huge cupcake, that does look a bit like a burger, spits black tobacco on his face at around 1:09):




+1 even if this isn't the answer because you made this connection.

Thanks. OP mentioning '94 triggered the memory (racked my brain for talking burger scenes till then).
